# WSO2 Identity Server does not show system statistics

Tags: wso2

I am having some trouble with Monitoring System Statistics in WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.3. There is no activity being reported in the Service Summary. We are about to go live with the WSO2 Identity server in a couple weeks, so I really want to keep an eye on the response time and counts.

Our current production system is not heavily used, but currently it shows Total Response Count: 0, when in fact I have tested several logins earlier today.

I know the monitoring was updating a few weeks ago, but something happened. Do I need to enable this via a setting or is it possible it was turned off?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Analytics) is the official documentation entry point on setting up and using statistics/analytics for latest WSO2 Identity server version. Please make sure you have followed all the steps accurately. You will have to separately enable it and configure in below files. After enabling you should be able to view stats.

```
<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml
<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers/IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-*
```